# Light approximation for shortest path tree

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, approximation

I am looking for the paper : "B. Awerbuch, A. Baratz, and D. Peleg, Eﬃcient broadcast and light-weight spanners, Manuscript, (1991)."
It claims that we can build $(\alpha ,1+\frac{4}{\alpha -1})-LAST$ where LAST hold for "Light Approximation Shortest path Tree"
if not available could any one explain the algorithms used there ?

Comment: may be this is close to what you looking for: http://arxiv.org/pdf/cs.ds/0205045.pdf

Comment: Its close but there result is optimal while I am looking for this one for my purposes!

Comment: It apparently ended up as a technical report: http://www.worldcat.org/title/efficient-broadcast-and-light-weight-spanners/oclc/30697695. You could ask one of the authors for a copy. (The third author's full name is David Peleg.)